# How to make a QTreeView display more than 10 lines

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7, qtreeview

**Using Python 3.7 with pyqt5 on Win10**

I am working on getting a QTreeView that uses a QStandardItemModel to display more than 10 lines. I want it to show the maximum number of lines the area can actually handle but it stops short at 10 for some unknown (by me at least) reason.

I have tried numerous solutions (some I have remarked out within the code below along with their apparent results) and there are others that I am not including because they did not compile. As of yet I cannot seem to find a way to get the QTreeView to fill the available space and/or show all the lines it can it just stops at 10 lines.  I am including a program that runs and shows the issue simply click "Options" then click "Option 1"

```
from sys  import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Line(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)

# Users Widget *************************************************
class Disply1(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.setLineWidth(0.2)
        # -------
        self.header = QVBoxLayout()
        Title = QLabel()
        Title.setStyleSheet('font: bold 14px')
        Title.setText('Option 1 Configuration Settings')
        self.header.addWidget(Title)
        self.header.addWidget(Line(self))
        # -------
        self.TreeVew = QTreeView()
        self.TreeVew.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.TreeVew.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
# This adjustment did not fix it
#        self.TreeVew.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Maximum)
# This adjustment made it worse
#        self.TreeVew.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(0, 6)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([' ', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5'])
        self.model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
# This adjustment did not fix it
#        self.model.setRowCount(20)
        self.TreeVew.setModel(self.model)

        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(0, 1)
        self.TreeVew.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.TreeVew.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Fixed)
        self.TreeVew.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.TreeVew.header().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(2, 100)
        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(3, 100)
        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(4, 100)
        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(5, 70)
# This adjustment did not fix it
#        self.TreeVew.resize(self.sizeHint().width(), self.maximumHeight())

        ItmRecSet = [
            {'Id':'01', 'Column1':'R01-C1',  'Column2':'R01-C2', 'Column3':'R01-C3',   'Column4':'R01-C5', 'Column5':'R01-C5'},
            {'Id':'02', 'Column1':'R02-C1',  'Column2':'R02-C2', 'Column3':'R02-C3',   'Column4':'R02-C5', 'Column5':'R02-C5'},
            {'Id':'03', 'Column1':'R03-C1',  'Column2':'R03-C2', 'Column3':'R03-C3',   'Column4':'R03-C5', 'Column5':'R03-C5'},
            {'Id':'04', 'Column1':'R04-C1',  'Column2':'R04-C2', 'Column3':'R04-C3',   'Column4':'R04-C5', 'Column5':'R04-C5'},
            {'Id':'05', 'Column1':'R05-C1',  'Column2':'R05-C2', 'Column3':'R05-C3',   'Column4':'R05-C5', 'Column5':'R05-C5'},
            {'Id':'06', 'Column1':'R06-C1',  'Column2':'R06-C2', 'Column3':'R06-C3',   'Column4':'R06-C5', 'Column5':'R06-C5'},
            {'Id':'07', 'Column1':'R07-C1',  'Column2':'R07-C2', 'Column3':'R07-C3',   'Column4':'R07-C5', 'Column5':'R07-C5'},
            {'Id':'08', 'Column1':'R08-C1',  'Column2':'R08-C2', 'Column3':'R08-C3',   'Column4':'R08-C5', 'Column5':'R08-C5'},
            {'Id':'09', 'Column1':'R09-C1',  'Column2':'R09-C2', 'Column3':'R09-C3',   'Column4':'R09-C5', 'Column5':'R09-C5'},
            {'Id':'10', 'Column1':'R10-C1',  'Column2':'R10-C2', 'Column3':'R10-C3',   'Column4':'R10-C5', 'Column5':'R10-C5'},
            {'Id':'11', 'Column1':'R11-C1',  'Column2':'R11-C2', 'Column3':'R11-C3',   'Column4':'R11-C5', 'Column5':'R11-C5'},
            {'Id':'12', 'Column1':'R12-C1',  'Column2':'R12-C2', 'Column3':'R12-C3',   'Column4':'R12-C5', 'Column5':'R12-C5'},
            {'Id':'13', 'Column1':'R13-C1',  'Column2':'R13-C2', 'Column3':'R13-C3',   'Column4':'R13-C5', 'Column5':'R13-C5'},
            {'Id':'14', 'Column1':'R14-C1',  'Column2':'R14-C2', 'Column3':'R14-C3',   'Column4':'R14-C5', 'Column5':'R14-C5'},
            {'Id':'15', 'Column1':'R15-C1',  'Column2':'R15-C2', 'Column3':'R15-C3',   'Column4':'R15-C5', 'Column5':'R15-C5'},
            {'Id':'16', 'Column1':'R16-C1',  'Column2':'R16-C2', 'Column3':'R16-C3',   'Column4':'R16-C5', 'Column5':'R16-C5'},
            {'Id':'17', 'Column1':'R17-C1',  'Column2':'R17-C2', 'Column3':'R17-C3',   'Column4':'R17-C5', 'Column5':'R17-C5'},
            {'Id':'18', 'Column1':'R18-C1',  'Column2':'R18-C2', 'Column3':'R18-C3',   'Column4':'R18-C5', 'Column5':'R18-C5'},
            {'Id':'19', 'Column1':'R19-C1',  'Column2':'R19-C2', 'Column3':'R19-C3',   'Column4':'R19-C5', 'Column5':'R19-C5'},
            {'Id':'20', 'Column1':'R20-C1',  'Column2':'R20-C2', 'Column3':'R20-C3',   'Column4':'R20-C5', 'Column5':'R20-C5'}
            ]
        self.model.setRowCount(0)

        for Item in ItmRecSet:
            Itm1 = QStandardItem(Item['Id'])
            Itm1.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm1.isEditable = False

            Itm2 = QStandardItem(Item['Column1'])
            Itm2.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm2.isEditable = False

            Itm3 = QStandardItem(Item['Column2'])
            Itm3.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm3.isEditable = False

            Itm4 = QStandardItem(Item['Column3'])
            Itm4.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm4.isEditable = False

            Itm5 = QStandardItem(Item['Column4'])
            Itm5.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm5.isEditable = False

            Itm6 = QStandardItem(Item['Column5'])
            Itm6.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            Itm6.isEditable = False

            self.model.appendRow([Itm1, Itm2, Itm3, Itm4, Itm5, Itm6])

# Using this GridLayout versus the VerticalBox did not fix it
#        self.Cntnr = QGridLayout()
        # -------
#        self.Cntnr.addLayout(self.header,0,0)
#        self.Cntnr.addWidget(self.TreeVew,1,0)
#        self.Cntnr.setRowStretch(2,4)

        self.Cntnr = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Cntnr.addLayout(self.header)
        self.Cntnr.addWidget(self.TreeVew)
# If this stretch is not included only the header gets stretched the QTreeView still only shows 10 lines
        self.Cntnr.addStretch(1)
        # -------
        self.setLayout(self.Cntnr)

# Debug Widget *************************************************
class Disply2(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.setLineWidth(0.2)
        # -------
        self.Cntnr = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Cntnr.addWidget(QTextEdit('Option 2 Settings Shown Here'))
        self.Cntnr.addStretch(1)
        # -------
        self.setLayout(self.Cntnr)

class OptionButtons(QToolButton):
# Class OptionButtons ("Text", Icon, Connector) inherits from QToolButton
    def __init__(self, Text, Icon, Connector):
        QToolButton.__init__(self)

        self.setText(Text)
        self.setIcon(Icon)
        self.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.setStyleSheet("font: bold;color: blue;height: 55px;width: 55px;")
        self.setIconSize(QSize(32,32))
        self.clicked.connect(Connector)

############################## Settings Class ##############################
class OptionSettings(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        line = QFrame()
        line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        line.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)

  # Button Area on Left
      # Button 1 *************************************************
        self.btnOptn1 = OptionButtons('Option1', QIcon('images/opt1.ico'), self.ShowDisply1)
      # Button 2 *************************************************
        self.btnOptn2 = OptionButtons('Option2', QIcon('images/opt2.ico'), self.ShowDisply2)
      # Vertical Box for Buttons *************************************
        self.UpLeft  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.UpLeft.addWidget(self.btnOptn1)
        self.UpLeft.addWidget(self.btnOptn2)
        self.UpLeft.addStretch(1)
  # Display Area on Right
      # Widget Flip Display ******************************************
        self.UpRite   = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Contents = QStackedWidget()
        self.Contents.addWidget(QTextEdit('Nothing Selected'))
        self.Contents.addWidget(Disply1(self))
        self.Contents.addWidget(Disply2(self))
        self.Contents.addWidget(QTextEdit('Settings Saved'))
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.UpRite.addWidget(self.Contents)

  # Button and Display Area on Top
        self.Upper = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Upper.addLayout(self.UpLeft)
        self.Upper.addLayout(self.UpRite)
  # Save and Cancel Area on Bottom
        self.btnSave = QPushButton("Save")
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(self.SaveSettings)
        self.btnCncl = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.btnCncl.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.Lower   = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Lower.addStretch(1)
        self.Lower.addWidget(self.btnSave)
        self.Lower.addWidget(self.btnCncl)
  # Entire Options Window Layout
        self.OuterBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.OuterBox.addLayout(self.Upper)
        self.OuterBox.addLayout(self.Lower)
        self.setLayout(self.OuterBox)
        self.setWindowTitle('Settings')
        #Geometry(Left, Top, Width, Hight)
        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 550, 450)
        self.setModal(True)
        self.exec()

    def ShowDisply1(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def ShowDisply2(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(2)

    def SaveSettings(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(3)

class CustomItemModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.blue)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.yellow)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setPointSize(10)
            return font

        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class ItemDsplyr(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, CentrPane)
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane

        self.setEditTriggers(QTreeView().NoEditTriggers)
        self.model = CustomItemModel(0, 3)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1st Col', '2nd Col', '3rd Col'])
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setMinimumWidth(250)

        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 75)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, 100)

class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.MyEditor = QTextEdit('Editorial')
        self.ItemDsply = ItemDsplyr(self)

        CntrPane = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.MyEditor)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.ItemDsply)
        CntrPane.setSizes([50,200])
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(0, False)
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(1, False)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(CntrPane)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

class MenuToolBar(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.MainMenu = MainWin.menuBar()

        self.WndowMenu  = self.MainMenu.addMenu('Windows')

        self.OptnAct = QAction('Options', self)
        self.OptnAct.setStatusTip('Open the Options Window')
        self.OptnAct.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowOptions)

        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.OptnAct)

        self.InitToolBar(MainWin)

    def InitToolBar(self, MainWin):
        self.mainToolBar = MainWin.addToolBar("Quick Access")

        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.OptnAct)

class UI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, MainDesktop):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(MainDesktop)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')

        self.MnDskTop = MainDesktop

      # Left, Top, Width, Height
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 550, 550)

        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.MenuToolBar = MenuToolBar(self)

    def ShowOptions(self):
        self.Options = OptionSettings(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp = QApplication([])

    MainGui = UI_MainWindow(MainApp.desktop())
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainApp.exec_())
```

Again what I had expected is that the QTreeView would fill the available space and/or show as many rows as possible within the given space.  However, as stated it stops short and only displays just 10 lines maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the line `self.Cntnr.addStretch(1)`, that's what happened:

```
from sys  import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Line(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        self.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)

# Users Widget *************************************************
class Disply1(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.setLineWidth(0.2) 
        # -------
        self.header = QVBoxLayout()
        Title = QLabel()
        Title.setStyleSheet('font: bold 14px')
        Title.setText('Option 1 Configuration Settings')
        self.header.addWidget(Title)
        self.header.addWidget(Line(self))

        # -------
        self.TreeVew = QTreeView()
        self.TreeVew.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.TreeVew.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
# This adjustment did not fix it
#        self.TreeVew.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Maximum)
# This adjustment made it worse
#        self.TreeVew.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(0, 6)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([' ', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5'])
        self.model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
# This adjustment did not fix it
#        self.model.setRowCount(20)
        self.TreeVew.setModel(self.model)

        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(0, 1)

        self.TreeVew.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.TreeVew.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Fixed)
        self.TreeVew.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.TreeVew.header().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(2, 100)
        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(3, 100)
        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(4, 100)
        self.TreeVew.setColumnWidth(5, 70)
# This adjustment did not fix it
#        self.TreeVew.resize(self.sizeHint().width(), self.maximumHeight())
#@        self.TreeVew.resize(400, 600)

        ItmRecSet = [
            {'Id':'01', 'Column1':'R01-C1',  'Column2':'R01-C2', 'Column3':'R01-C3',   'Column4':'R01-C5', 'Column5':'R01-C5'},
            {'Id':'02', 'Column1':'R02-C1',  'Column2':'R02-C2', 'Column3':'R02-C3',   'Column4':'R02-C5', 'Column5':'R02-C5'},
            {'Id':'03', 'Column1':'R03-C1',  'Column2':'R03-C2', 'Column3':'R03-C3',   'Column4':'R03-C5', 'Column5':'R03-C5'},
            {'Id':'04', 'Column1':'R04-C1',  'Column2':'R04-C2', 'Column3':'R04-C3',   'Column4':'R04-C5', 'Column5':'R04-C5'},
            {'Id':'05', 'Column1':'R05-C1',  'Column2':'R05-C2', 'Column3':'R05-C3',   'Column4':'R05-C5', 'Column5':'R05-C5'},
            {'Id':'06', 'Column1':'R06-C1',  'Column2':'R06-C2', 'Column3':'R06-C3',   'Column4':'R06-C5', 'Column5':'R06-C5'},
            {'Id':'07', 'Column1':'R07-C1',  'Column2':'R07-C2', 'Column3':'R07-C3',   'Column4':'R07-C5', 'Column5':'R07-C5'},
            {'Id':'08', 'Column1':'R08-C1',  'Column2':'R08-C2', 'Column3':'R08-C3',   'Column4':'R08-C5', 'Column5':'R08-C5'},
            {'Id':'09', 'Column1':'R09-C1',  'Column2':'R09-C2', 'Column3':'R09-C3',   'Column4':'R09-C5', 'Column5':'R09-C5'},
            {'Id':'10', 'Column1':'R10-C1',  'Column2':'R10-C2', 'Column3':'R10-C3',   'Column4':'R10-C5', 'Column5':'R10-C5'},
            {'Id':'11', 'Column1':'R11-C1',  'Column2':'R11-C2', 'Column3':'R11-C3',   'Column4':'R11-C5', 'Column5':'R11-C5'},
            {'Id':'12', 'Column1':'R12-C1',  'Column2':'R12-C2', 'Column3':'R12-C3',   'Column4':'R12-C5', 'Column5':'R12-C5'},
            {'Id':'13', 'Column1':'R13-C1',  'Column2':'R13-C2', 'Column3':'R13-C3',   'Column4':'R13-C5', 'Column5':'R13-C5'},
            {'Id':'14', 'Column1':'R14-C1',  'Column2':'R14-C2', 'Column3':'R14-C3',   'Column4':'R14-C5', 'Column5':'R14-C5'},
            {'Id':'15', 'Column1':'R15-C1',  'Column2':'R15-C2', 'Column3':'R15-C3',   'Column4':'R15-C5', 'Column5':'R15-C5'},
            {'Id':'16', 'Column1':'R16-C1',  'Column2':'R16-C2', 'Column3':'R16-C3',   'Column4':'R16-C5', 'Column5':'R16-C5'},
            {'Id':'17', 'Column1':'R17-C1',  'Column2':'R17-C2', 'Column3':'R17-C3',   'Column4':'R17-C5', 'Column5':'R17-C5'},
            {'Id':'18', 'Column1':'R18-C1',  'Column2':'R18-C2', 'Column3':'R18-C3',   'Column4':'R18-C5', 'Column5':'R18-C5'},
            {'Id':'19', 'Column1':'R19-C1',  'Column2':'R19-C2', 'Column3':'R19-C3',   'Column4':'R19-C5', 'Column5':'R19-C5'},
            {'Id':'20', 'Column1':'R20-C1',  'Column2':'R20-C2', 'Column3':'R20-C3',   'Column4':'R20-C5', 'Column5':'R20-C5'}
            ]
        self.model.setRowCount(0)

        for Item in ItmRecSet:
            Itm1 = QStandardItem(Item['Id'])
            Itm1.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm1.isEditable = False

            Itm2 = QStandardItem(Item['Column1'])
            Itm2.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm2.isEditable = False

            Itm3 = QStandardItem(Item['Column2'])
            Itm3.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm3.isEditable = False

            Itm4 = QStandardItem(Item['Column3'])
            Itm4.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm4.isEditable = False

            Itm5 = QStandardItem(Item['Column4'])
            Itm5.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            Itm5.isEditable = False

            Itm6 = QStandardItem(Item['Column5'])
            Itm6.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            Itm6.isEditable = False

            self.model.appendRow([Itm1, Itm2, Itm3, Itm4, Itm5, Itm6])

# Using this GridLayout versus the VerticalBox did not fix it
#        self.Cntnr = QGridLayout()
        # -------
#        self.Cntnr.addLayout(self.header,0,0)
#        self.Cntnr.addWidget(self.TreeVew,1,0)
#        self.Cntnr.setRowStretch(2,4)

        self.Cntnr = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Cntnr.addLayout(self.header)
        self.Cntnr.addWidget(self.TreeVew)

# If this stretch is not included only the header gets stretched the QTreeView still only shows 10 lines

#---        self.Cntnr.addStretch(1)                                     # <<<=======

        # -------
        self.setLayout(self.Cntnr)

# Debug Widget *************************************************
class Disply2(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QFrame.__init__(self)

        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.setLineWidth(0.2)
        # -------
        self.Cntnr = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Cntnr.addWidget(QTextEdit('Option 2 Settings Shown Here'))
        self.Cntnr.addStretch(1)
        # -------
        self.setLayout(self.Cntnr)

class OptionButtons(QToolButton):
# Class OptionButtons ("Text", Icon, Connector) inherits from QToolButton
    def __init__(self, Text, Icon, Connector):
        QToolButton.__init__(self)

        self.setText(Text)
        self.setIcon(Icon)
        self.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.setStyleSheet("font: bold;color: blue;height: 55px;width: 55px;")
        self.setIconSize(QSize(32,32))
        self.clicked.connect(Connector)

############################## Settings Class ##############################
class OptionSettings(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        line = QFrame()
        line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        line.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)

  # Button Area on Left
      # Button 1 *************************************************
        self.btnOptn1 = OptionButtons('Option1', QIcon('Ok.png'), self.ShowDisply1)
      # Button 2 *************************************************
        self.btnOptn2 = OptionButtons('Option2', QIcon('images/opt2.ico'), self.ShowDisply2)
      # Vertical Box for Buttons *************************************
        self.UpLeft  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.UpLeft.addWidget(self.btnOptn1)
        self.UpLeft.addWidget(self.btnOptn2)
        self.UpLeft.addStretch(1)
  # Display Area on Right
      # Widget Flip Display ******************************************
        self.UpRite   = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Contents = QStackedWidget()
        self.Contents.addWidget(QTextEdit('Nothing Selected'))
        self.Contents.addWidget(Disply1(self))
        self.Contents.addWidget(Disply2(self))
        self.Contents.addWidget(QTextEdit('Settings Saved'))
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.UpRite.addWidget(self.Contents)

  # Button and Display Area on Top
        self.Upper = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Upper.addLayout(self.UpLeft)
        self.Upper.addLayout(self.UpRite)
  # Save and Cancel Area on Bottom
        self.btnSave = QPushButton("Save")
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(self.SaveSettings)
        self.btnCncl = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.btnCncl.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.Lower   = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Lower.addStretch(1)
        self.Lower.addWidget(self.btnSave)
        self.Lower.addWidget(self.btnCncl)
  # Entire Options Window Layout
        self.OuterBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.OuterBox.addLayout(self.Upper)
        self.OuterBox.addLayout(self.Lower)
        self.setLayout(self.OuterBox)
        self.setWindowTitle('Settings')
        #Geometry(Left, Top, Width, Hight)
        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 550, 450)
        self.setModal(True)
        self.exec()

    def ShowDisply1(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def ShowDisply2(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(2)

    def SaveSettings(self):
        self.Contents.setCurrentIndex(3)

class CustomItemModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.blue)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.yellow)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setPointSize(10)
            return font

        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class ItemDsplyr(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, CentrPane)
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane

        self.setEditTriggers(QTreeView().NoEditTriggers)
        self.model = CustomItemModel(0, 3)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1st Col', '2nd Col', '3rd Col'])
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setMinimumWidth(250)

        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 75)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, 100)

class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.MyEditor = QTextEdit('Editorial')
        self.ItemDsply = ItemDsplyr(self)

        CntrPane = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.MyEditor)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.ItemDsply)
        CntrPane.setSizes([50,200])
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(0, False)
        CntrPane.setCollapsible(1, False)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(CntrPane)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

class MenuToolBar(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.MainMenu = MainWin.menuBar()

        self.WndowMenu  = self.MainMenu.addMenu('Windows')

        self.OptnAct = QAction('Options', self)
        self.OptnAct.setStatusTip('Open the Options Window')
        self.OptnAct.triggered.connect(MainWin.ShowOptions)

        self.WndowMenu.addAction(self.OptnAct)

        self.InitToolBar(MainWin)

    def InitToolBar(self, MainWin):
        self.mainToolBar = MainWin.addToolBar("Quick Access")

        self.mainToolBar.addAction(self.OptnAct)

class UI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, MainDesktop):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(MainDesktop)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')

        self.MnDskTop = MainDesktop

      # Left, Top, Width, Height
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 550, 550)

        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.MenuToolBar = MenuToolBar(self)

    def ShowOptions(self):
        self.Options = OptionSettings(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp = QApplication([])

    MainGui = UI_MainWindow(MainApp.desktop())
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainApp.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Okay that is plain weird because when I remarked that line out what it did the first few tests I ran was to stretch the header line and still only display 10 lines but its working now perhaps I adjusted something else unknowingly. Still thanks for looking at it